# MongoDB Aggregate by hour and sum wrong results

Tags: mongodb

So I have a collection with this documents

```
 { 
    "_id" : {
        "ad_id" : NumberInt(1915577), 
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-12T22:00:00.000+0000")
    }, 
    "history" : [
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-13T13:31:23.536+0000"), 
            "mobile" : true, 
            "app" : false, 
            "origin" : NumberInt(2)
        },
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-13T13:43:11.512+0000"), 
            "mobile" : true, 
            "app" : false, 
            "origin" : NumberInt(2)
        },
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-13T20:31:05.156+0000"), 
            "mobile" : true, 
            "app" : false, 
            "origin" : NumberInt(6)
        },
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-13T21:14:09.236+0000"), 
            "mobile" : false, 
            "app" : false, 
            "origin" : NumberInt(3)
        }
    ], 
    "impressions_mobile" : NumberInt(10),
    "impressions_desktop" : NumberInt(3),
}
```

I want to get how many "mobile" and "not mobile" items I have in my history array, grouped by each hour of the day (from 00 to 23h)

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "y": 2018,
            "m": 6,
            "d": 13,
            "h": 13
        },
        "mobile": 4,
        "desktop": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "y": 2018,
            "m": 6,
            "d": 13,
            "h": 20
        },
        "mobile": 6,
        "desktop": 3
    }
]
```

I've tried query like this one, which gives no result... if I remove the `$unwind` and the group `_id` object (I set it to null) I get the numbers.. I've tried many other queries but can't get it working.

Basically I want to group by day and hour my results and get how many of them I have...

```
db.mycol.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
             "ad.advertiser": 1399619,
            "_id.createdAt": {
                $gte: ISODate("2018-06-12T22:00:00.000+0000"),
                $lte: ISODate("2018-06-14T22:00:00.000+0000")
            }
        }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: "$history",
        mobile: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$history",
                as: "h",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$h.mobile", true ] }
            }
        },
        desktop: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$history",
                as: "h",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$h.mobile", false ] }
            }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: "$history",
        mobile: { $size: "$mobile" },
        desktop: { $size: "$desktop" },
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$_id" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "y": {
                    "$year": "$_id.createdAt"
                },
                "m": {
                    "$month": "$_id.createdAt"
                },
                "d": {
                    "$dayOfMonth": "$_id.createdAt"
                },
                "h": {
                    "$hour": "$_id.createdAt"
                }
            },
            mobile: { $sum: "$mobile" },
            desktop: { $sum: "$desktop" }
        }
    }
])
```

This other query works but gives me wrong results

```
db.mycol.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
             "ad.advertiser": 1399619,
            "_id.createdAt": {
                $gte: ISODate("2018-06-12T22:00:00.000+0000"),
                $lte: ISODate("2018-06-14T22:00:00.000+0000")
            }
        }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$history",
                as: "h",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$h.mobile", true ] }
            }
        }
      }
    },
    { $project: { _id: "$_id",  mobile: { $size: "$_id" } } },
    { $unwind: "$_id" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "y": {
                    "$year": "$_id.createdAt"
                },
                "m": {
                    "$month": "$_id.createdAt"
                },
                "d": {
                    "$dayOfMonth": "$_id.createdAt"
                },
                "h": {
                    "$hour": "$_id.createdAt"
                }
            },
            mobile: { $sum: "$mobile" }
        }
    }
])
```

Field `mobile` outputs a huge number, for example instead of ~200 (which is the real result) it gives me ~8000 and I don't know what is it doing...

I would love to get desktop and mobile results all together but I don't mind to get it in two queries

UPDATE: I pasted the wrong query, sorry ^^'

UPDATE2:
`$_id.createdAt` is always a midnight date (in UTC so it is 22h), every document in the collection is treated as a "On this day, we had this" then inside the `history` field we have the exact time when things happened.

If I group by hour on `_id.createdAt` field everything will be inside the same hour, not the 24 hours a day has.

For exmaple a result grouping by `_id.createdAt` will always be

`{
    "y": 2018,
    "m": 6,
    "d": 13,
    "h": 00,
    "mobile": 100,
    "desktop": 35
}`

So `_id.createdAt` is ONLY for matching that particular day, and only for that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get how many "mobile" and "not mobile" items I have in my `history` array, grouped by each hour of the day (from 00 to 23h). @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Comment: Why you have both `mobile` and `app` flag? Is there some device is not categorized as `mobile` nor `app`?

Comment: Everything that is not `mobile` is considered as `desktop` that's why I only check for `mobile: true` or `mobile: false`. The collection is not mine, it is a crazy mess, I am trying to migrate all the data we have into a better model and it is being a pain in the ass :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `$cond` operation to sum:

```
db.mycol.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
             "ad.advertiser": 1399619,
            "_id.createdAt": {
                $gte: ISODate("2018-06-12T22:00:00.000+0000"),
                $lte: ISODate("2018-06-14T22:00:00.000+0000")
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$history"},
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "y": { "$year": "$_id.createdAt" },
                "m": { "$month": "$_id.createdAt" },
                "d": { "$dayOfMonth": "$_id.createdAt "},
                "h": { "$hour": "$_id.createdAt" }
            },
            "mobile": {$sum: {$cond: ["$history.mobile", 1, 0]}},
            "desktop": {$sum: {$cond: ["$history.mobile", 0, 1]}},
        }
    }

])
```

Comment: That won't work because `$_id.createdAt` is always a midnight date, every document in the collection is treated as a "On this day, we had this" then inside the `history` field we have the exact time when things happened.

If I group by hour on `_id.createdAt` field everything will be inside the same hour, not the 24 hours a day has, I need the `history.createdAt` field >.<

Comment: I've changed `_id.createdAt` to `history.createdAt` and it looks promising, I am leaving office right now so I'll double check data tomorrow and give you feedback on it.